# Nuxt + Vue 3: Make all table columns sortable and isolate sort click action to just change icons on sorted column

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a table where all columns are sortable, the sort function is working fine but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to make my icons change direction just for the column that I choose to sort. With my approach every time I click on an icon all the other icons will also change direction, I know why this is happening (I just evaluating to show or not show the icons based on the currentSortDir state property (asc or desc) and I also know that I have to give every column some sort of name to evaluate my state property currentSort (that will have the name of the current sort column) but I can't figure out how to make this work with something like a v-if, maybe I have to change my template structure? I'm not using a multiple class method in order to change my sort icons but two svg's that will show conditionally depending on the sorting method.

Template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-center font-semibold">Agents</h1>
    <div class="px-4 mt-6">
      <table class="text-left w-full">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="px-4 py-2" @click="sort('email')">
              <div
                class="bg-gray-300 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center"
              >
                <span>
                  <IconBase
                    v-if="currentSortDir === 'asc'"
                    class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                    icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                    icon-name="asc"
                    ><IconAsc
                  /></IconBase>
                  <IconBase
                    v-if="currentSortDir === 'desc'"
                    class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                    icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                    icon-name="desc"
                    ><IconDesc
                  /></IconBase>
                </span>
                <span>Name</span>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="px-4 py-2" @click="sort('email')">
              <div
                class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center"
              >
                <span>
                  <IconBase
                    v-if="currentSortDir === 'asc'"
                    class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                    icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                    icon-name="asc"
                    ><IconAsc
                  /></IconBase>
                  <IconBase
                    v-if="currentSortDir === 'desc'"
                    class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                    icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                    icon-name="desc"
                    ><IconDesc
                  /></IconBase>
                </span>
                <span>Email</span>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="px-4 py-2" @click="sort('wsConnectionStatus')">
              <div
                class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center"
              >
                <span>
                  <IconBase
                    v-if="currentSortDir === 'asc'"
                    class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                    icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                    icon-name="checkmark"
                    ><IconAsc
                  /></IconBase>
                  <IconBase
                    v-if="currentSortDir === 'desc'"
                    class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                    icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                    icon-name="checkmark"
                    ><IconDesc
                  /></IconBase>
                </span>
                <span>WS</span>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="px-4 py-2" @click="sort('status')">
              <div
                class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center"
              >
                <IconBase
                  v-if="currentSortDir === 'asc'"
                  class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                  icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                  icon-name="checkmark"
                  ><IconAsc
                /></IconBase>
                <IconBase
                  v-if="currentSortDir === 'desc'"
                  class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                  icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                  icon-name="checkmark"
                  ><IconDesc
                /></IconBase>
                <span>Status</span>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="px-4 py-2" @click="sort('priorityRank')">
              <button
                class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center"
              >
                <IconBase
                  v-if="currentSortDir === 'asc'"
                  class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                  icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                  icon-name="checkmark"
                  ><IconAsc
                /></IconBase>
                <IconBase
                  v-if="currentSortDir === 'desc'"
                  class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                  icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                  icon-name="checkmark"
                  ><IconDesc
                /></IconBase>
                <span>Rank</span>
              </button>
            </th>
            <th class="px-4 py-2" @click="sort('numberChats')">
              <button
                class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center"
              >
                <IconBase
                  v-if="currentSortDir === 'asc'"
                  class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                  icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                  icon-name="checkmark"
                  ><IconAsc
                /></IconBase>
                <IconBase
                  v-if="currentSortDir === 'desc'"
                  class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                  icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                  icon-name="checkmark"
                  ><IconDesc
                /></IconBase>
                <span>Number Chats</span>
              </button>
            </th>
            <th class="px-4 py-2" @click="sort('currentMaxChats')">
              <button
                class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center"
              >
                <IconBase
                  v-if="currentSortDir === 'asc'"
                  class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                  icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                  icon-name="checkmark"
                  ><IconAsc
                /></IconBase>
                <IconBase
                  v-if="currentSortDir === 'desc'"
                  class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
                  icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
                  icon-name="checkmark"
                  ><IconDesc
                /></IconBase>
                <span>Max Current</span>
              </button>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <Agent
            v-for="(agent, index) in sortedAgents"
            :key="index"
            :agent="agent"
            :data-index="index"
          ></Agent>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

State:

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import IconBase from '@/components/Icons/IconBase.vue'
import IconAsc from '@/components/Icons/IconAsc.vue'
import IconDesc from '@/components/Icons/IconDesc.vue'
import Agent from '@/components/Agent.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    Agent,
    IconBase,
    IconAsc,
    IconDesc,
  },
  async fetch({ store, error }) {
    try {
      await store.dispatch('agents/fetchAgents')
    } catch (e) {
      error({
        statusCode: 503,
        message: 'Unable to fetch events at this time. Please try again later',
      })
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentSort: 'email',
      currentSortDir: 'asc',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      agents: (state) => state.agents.agents,
    }),
    sortedAgents() {
      return this.agents.slice().sort((a, b) => {
        let modifier = 1
        if (this.currentSortDir === 'desc') modifier = -1
        if (a[this.currentSort] < b[this.currentSort]) return -1 * modifier
        if (a[this.currentSort] > b[this.currentSort]) return 1 * modifier
        return 0
      })
    },
  },
  methods: {
    sort(columnToSort) {
      if (columnToSort === this.currentSort) {
        this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
      }
      this.currentSort = columnToSort
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only 1 column can be ascending at a time, just add the currentSort to the conditionals.

```
<IconBase
  v-if="currentSortDir === 'asc' && currentSort === 'email'"
  class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
  icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
  icon-name="checkmark"
  >
  <IconAsc/>
</IconBase>
<IconBase
  v-else
  class="fill-current w-4 h-4 mr-2"
  icon-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.80)"
  icon-name="checkmark"
  >
  <IconDesc/>
</IconBase>
```

Note the `v-else` in the desc icon.

Regarding the double-click issue, try this:

```
if (columnToSort === this.currentSort) {
  this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
} else {
  this.currentSortDir = 'asc'
}
this.currentSort = columnToSort
```

Comment: Many thanks, @NickDawes, that made the trick. Just one thing, I'm noticing that the sort call to action (the <TH> tags) does not react on the first click but on the second. Do you know what is happening there?

Comment: Also: your suggestion for the sort method is not working. !this.currentSortdir makes currentSortdir = false and breaks the code since I want a value of "asc" or "desc" for that state property.

Comment: It looks like you have a conditional in the method, that checks to see if ```currentSort``` is equal to the string you pass in when clicking the TH the first time. This is false on the first click. The second time you click it, ```currentSort``` has been updated to the string you’ve passed in via the first click, so the conditional is true and only then does  ```currentSortDir``` get updated.

Comment: You are totally correct, my mistake regarding the Boolean switch! I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer with a suggestion to fix the double click issue.